# Identify six months of continuous enrollment period

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data snippet:

| ID | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-31 |
| 1 | 2015-02-01 | 2015-02-28 |
| 1 | 2015-03-01 | 2015-03-31 |
| 1 | 2015-04-01 | 2015-04-30 |
| 1 | 2015-05-01 | 2015-05-31 |
| 1 | 2015-06-01 | 2015-06-30 |
| 1 | 2016-07-01 | 2016-07-31 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-31 |
| 2 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-31 |

I need to identify/flag ids that have six or more continuous months of enrollment. I tried using max and partition by id but it yields the maximum value as 2020 which would be incorrect. Any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: Use CTEs to check the value of the start date is the day after th prior end date, then put the rows into groups based on if they were or not; then you have a gaps and island issue?

Answer (score 0):

A technique for locating "gaps and islands" in data can be used for this problem:

- Use a subquery to calculate the number of days between the end date of the previous row and the start date of the current row.
- Assign a row number to each row based on start date.
- Calculate the difference between row numbers and group consecutive rows together.
- Select the minimum start date, maximum end date, and sum of days for each group.

.

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT ID, start_dt, end_dt, days, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY start_dt
            ) AS rn
    FROM (
        SELECT *, coalesce(datediff(day, lag(end_dt, 1) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_dt
                        ), start_dt), 1) AS days
        FROM your_table
        ) d
    )
  , CTE2 AS (
    SELECT ID, start_dt, end_dt, days, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY start_dt
            ) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ID, days ORDER BY start_dt
            ) AS grp
    FROM CTE
    )
SELECT ID, grp, MIN(start_dt) AS start_dt, MAX(end_dt) AS end_dt, SUM(days) AS days
FROM CTE2
GROUP BY ID, grp
ORDER BY ID, start_dt;
```

I added some additional data for testing, this is the unfiltered result. Add a where clause, or having clause (e.g. `having count(*) >= 6`), to limit which rows get returned:

| ID | grp | start_dt | end_dt | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2005-01-01 | 2005-06-30 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 | 2006-07-01 | 2006-07-31 | 366 |
| 1 | 7 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-31 | 3076 |
| 1 | 2 | 2015-02-01 | 2015-06-30 | 5 |
| 1 | 13 | 2016-07-01 | 2016-07-31 | 367 |
| 1 | 14 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-31 | 1249 |
| 2 | 15 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-31 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UcmrneCS)